# NaNs create problems in scikit-learn

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, nan

My dataframe looks like this:

```
  testId    wordNumber_no    difficulty    containsPhoto     complicatedWords     Verdict
0     t1              140           NaN                0         7.653800e+06        Easy
1     t2              300           NaN                1         7.645800e+06        Hard
2     t3              394  7.653800e+06                0                  NaN        Hard
...
```

To predict the `Verdict` I easily used XGBoost and it worked well. I wanted to try **AdaBoost** too.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import metrics

cols_to_drop = ['testId'] 
df.drop(cols_to_drop, axis=1, inplace=True)
X = df.drop('Verdict', axis=1)
y = df['Verdict']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=5) #not sure if random_state is needed, it fails both with and without it

abc = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=50, learning_rate=1)
model = abc.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
```

But when fitting the model I get `ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')`.

**What I did:**

Since `df.isnull().any()` returns Trues, I did `df = df.fillna(method='ffill')`, but the error persists. Then I tried `df = df.fillna(lambda x: x.median())`, but I get `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'function'`, because of the lambda function. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: `ffill` won't necessarilly fill all NaNs. I think if there are NaNs at the very beginning of a column (i.e., no non-NaNs before them to ffill with), they'll stay nan.

Comment: Instead of `df.fillna(method='ffill')`, try this: `df.ffill().bfill()`

Comment: @user17242583 you are right, I checked and it doesn't remove all of them. But certain columns are full of NaNs...

Comment: @user17242583 I tried and it removes even less NaNs :))

Comment: Really? copying and pasting your df and using bfill+ffill like that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can drop all rows that contains NaN

   ```
    df.dropna()
   ```
2. Replace NaN by column mean value. Use it for all columns

   ```
    df[col].fillna(df[col].mean())
   ```

Make sure that you first removed all NaN from the initial dataset, then made training and test samples from it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll give it a try. However, I have a couple of columns that contain lots of NaNs (which I could get away with in XGBoost, strangely enough), will this affect my model?

Comment: df.dropna() returns a dataframe with 0 rows, oops.

Comment: It worked with `df=df.fillna(df.mean())`.